# Check if property value exists

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

i'm looking for a way to check if a value does already exists.
My current way is:

```
store.createQuery(MyClass.class).field(property).equal(value).countAll() > 0;
```

Is this the most efficient way or is there a better way to do this?
I don't need count all, the first match is enough.

Comment: Could we ask "what is the purpose?" Usually if you state "why" you want to do this and "what you really want to do" then there is another and more concise answer, as opposed to the question you are currently asking.

Comment: My purpose is to check if an username or email already exists (for example by a registration). I have an unique index but the DuplicateKeyException has no information about the property except i would parse the error string. (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1352)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be really looking for the ["createIfMissing"](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Updating#createifmissing-overload-parameter) or general MongoDB "upsert" behavior. What this does is id the query condition does not find a document to update then a new document is created:

```
ops = store.createUpdateOperations(MyClass.class).set("name", "This Value");
store.updateFirst(MyClass.class).field(property).equal(value), ops, true)
```

Also look at the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator and [`.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method from the core MongoDB documentation.

Comment: I don't want insert if missing.
My workflow is:

Request from Client
Check if exists
Return error for dupplicate username

I need realy just a simple check. But countAll seems not to be the most efficient way.

Comment: @Dominic "upsert" means insert if a "duplicate" does not exist. Two operations as compared to one is never more efficient. If you mean something else then your question lacks in clarity.